# Dynamically create new List<strings> and add n number of lines - C#

Tags: c#, list, streamreader

I'm trying to read a file using StreamReader. The file contains the data below (and 40,000 more lines!):

```
    Tyndall Centre grim file created on 22.01.2004 at 17:57 by Dr. Tim Mitchell
.pre = precipitation (mm)
CRU TS 2.1
[Long=-180.00, 180.00] [Lati= -90.00,  90.00] [Grid X,Y= 720, 360]
[Boxes=   67420] [Years=1991-2000] [Multi=    0.1000] [Missing=-999]
Grid-ref=   1, 148
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
Grid-ref=   1, 311
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
Grid-ref=   1, 312
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
```

I've managed to read the first 5 lines and add those lines to a List. Right now, I'm wanting to read the line containing:

> Grid-ref=   1, 148

and the following 10 line so it finishes reading just before:

> Grid-ref=   1, 311

I then want to add these lines to a new List however, I don't want to create a new List over and over again.

So far, it captures these two lines:

> Grid-ref=   1, 148
>
> 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

Here is what I have so far:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var list = new List<string>();
    List<string> HeaderParse = new List<string>();

    List<string> GridRefList = new List<string>();


    var regex = new Regex(@"(Grid-ref)");

    using (var sr = new StreamReader("cru-ts-2-10.1991-2000-cutdown.pre"))
    {
        string line;
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            list.Add(line);
        }

        for(int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++)
        {
            if (!regex.IsMatch(list[a]))
            {
                HeaderParse.Add(list[a]);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int b = 0; b < list.Count; b++)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(list[b]))
            {
                GridRefList.Add(list[b]);

                b++;

                if (!regex.IsMatch(list[b]))
                {
                    GridRefList.Add(list[b]);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    MessageBox.Show("This button has been clicked");
}
```

*I require help on how to tell the StreamReader to read the next 10 lines after the match and create a new List for when it encounters a new line containing "Grid-ref".*

Comment: What type of file is this? Is there an already existent parser available somewhere so you do not have to re-invent it?

Comment: Will you be processing each of these groups between the header lines one at a time?

Comment: Also how will you be using the lines with numbers?  Might be worth writing a class to hold the data in each group

Comment: @Igor It's a .pre file.

Comment: There are much better ways to read in an entire file - consider `File.ReadLines`. You don't need a `Regex` to match a string. Where do you want the new `List` stored?

Comment: @ParrishHusband I'd like to add the lines underneath each of the 'Grid-ref' headers to the same list as the header.

Comment: So to confirm, you want to add each header and the ten-ish lines below it to a list of its own? For example, if you have 3 headers and 10 lines of numbers below each, you'd have 3 lists of size 11 (first item in list is header, next 10 are number lines)? Is that correct?

Comment: I am not familiar with that extension. Do you have a link to more information about it?

Comment: @NetMage I already started with StreamReader so I'm kinda set on using this. Especially since I havent used it before.

Comment: @Sach Yes, that's exactly what I want to accomplish

Comment: @Igor Here is more information about this file extension: https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/pre

Comment: My spam anti-virus blocked that link due to malware....

Comment: @MOMI `StreamReader` is fine, but reading the entire file into a `List` only to process the `List` one line at a time is just wasting memory. Read and process each line and dump the `List` buffer.

Comment: @NetMage wouldn't that be counter intuitive in the bigger scheme of things though? At this day and age, reading a file that has few thousand (or even hundred thousand) lines into memory isn't that big of a performance factor. On the other hand, if in the future this project comes to a point where the file is written to and read at the same time, holding file open for that long could be a bigger issue? I'm trying to see pros and cons.

Comment: @Igor Here's a little extract from the site "The PRE file extension is used for data files created through IBM’s Lotus Freelance Graphics, a program developed by Lotus Software intended to create presentations and information graphics. The application was originally created as an enhancement for the Lotus’ spreadsheet program. It enables users to create, compile and arrange freely chosen objects such as text, diagrams, charts, tables, digital images and basic drawings into a digital slide show."

Comment: @Sach, well you can't (easily) read or write a text file at the same time. Also, the code shown doesn't close the file after it reads it in, it still holds it open until processed. And it processes the read-in file twice.

Comment: Well I didn't really mean _at the same time_, if it is a file that the system both writes to and reads from, then it would have to wait longer to write if it is being read for a long time (comparatively). I agree it should have a `using` for a `FileStream` first.

Answer (score 1):

This is less of an answer to your specific question and more of a possible design implementation route you could take.  Not sure how the data is going to be used, but you can manually serialize this data into custom classes that support the type of work you want to do:

```
public class PrecipitationFile
{
    string FileName { get; }
    public IList<PrecipitationGrid> Grids { get; }
    int BoxCount { get; }
    double Multi { get; }
    int Missing { get; }
    IList<string> Years { get; }

    public PrecipitationFile(string filePath)
    {
        // Read file, set properties, split by grid-ref chunks
        // Grids.Add(new PrecipitationGrid(this, chunk));
    }
}

public class PrecipitationGrid
{
    int Id { get; }
    int Ref { get; }
    PrecipitationFile Header { get; }
    string Source { get; }
    IList<int> GridNumbers { get; set; }

    public PrecipitationGrid(PrecipitationFile header, string source)
    {
        // set properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of lists. Every time you come upon "Grid-ref", make a new list at depth 1. Add the 10 lines or so of data at depth 2. This way all your data is contained in one big List, but neatly segmented.

```
List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
var list = new List<string>();
var regex = new Regex(@"(Grid-ref)");

using (var sr = new StreamReader("cru-ts-2-10.1991-2000-cutdown.pre"))
{
    string line;
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(line);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (regex.IsMatch(list[i])) //line matches "Grid=ref"
        {
            List<string> data_block = new List<string>(); //data_block is for the 10 lines
            data.Add(data_block); //add data_block list to bigger 2D list
        }
        else //other data
        {
            data[data.Count].Add(list[i]); //put other data into the most recent list
        }
    }
}
```

You also don't need to use Regex, as it is a costly operation. I would recommend replacing it with

```
if(list[i].Contains("Grid-ref"))
```

Comment: This won't work because of the first 5 lines. It will go to the `else` at the first line and cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Right, I didn't see that part of the file, but it is a simple fix. Have a boolean set to true once "Grid-ref" is read. If that is true, then add to the list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't try to do file reads and data manipulations all at once. First read the file and put it into a simple list of strings and be done with file read. Then, manipulate the data. I've added comments so it should be self-explanatory.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = ReadFile("input.txt");

    List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
    var firstHeader = false;
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (!firstHeader && line.StartsWith("Grid-ref="))
        {
            // Found the first header
            firstHeader = true;
            // Let's create a new list and add the header.
            var newList = new List<string> { line };
            data.Add(newList);
        }
        else if (firstHeader && !line.StartsWith("Grid-ref="))
        {
            // Now we're at the number lines to its corresponding list.
            data.Last<List<string>>().Add(line);
        }
        else if (firstHeader && line.StartsWith("Grid-ref="))
        {
            // Found the next header.
            // So we create next list and add the header.
            var newList = new List<string> { line };
            data.Add(newList);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static List<string> ReadFile(string file)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            list.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Here's how `data` looks like at the end.

[image]